# geom_point, colour by factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, spatial

I am trying to create some maps in R utilising `ggplot2`. I've reached a point where I have the final map I want spatially, but need to change the shape and colour of the points according to categorial factors.

The data frame is called genAQ in this context. Each row contains longitude and latitude, quality (high/low) and species (3 sp). Eventually, I would like the point colour to be in accordance with species, and the point shape to be in accordance with quality.

```
#correct spatial map, but all points are black. This code works perfectly.
ggplot(data=world) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_point(data=genAQ, aes(x=Lon, y=Lat), size=1,
             shape = 19, col = "black") +
  geom_polygon(data=lakes10, aes(long, lat, group = group), fill="lightblue") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(133.75, 140.52), ylim = c(-26.75, -31.30), expand=F)
```

Now I try to change the colour, utilising species as a factor. 
If I were coding using the plot function, I would write it as

```
plot(genAQ$Lat~genAQ$Lon, pch=19, col=genAQ$Species).
```

Using this same principle, I try to apply it to the initial code which works.

```
ggplot(data=world) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_point(data=genAQ, aes(x=Lon, y=Lat), size=1,
             shape = 19, col = genAQ$Species) +
  geom_polygon(data=lakes10, aes(long, lat, group = group), fill="lightblue") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(133.75, 140.52), ylim = c(-26.75, -31.30), expand=F)
```

It comes back with an error:

> Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colour, TRUE) : 
>     invalid color name 'Amytornis modestus indulkanna'.

So clearly `ggplot` does not understand the same language I'm using in the `plot()` function, as it's still trying to read the colour as a colour, rather than a categorical factor. I've tried other methods I've seen on StackOverflow, but I can't seem to find an answer for a seemly simple problem.

Comment: The answer is probably something like `geom_point(data=genAQ, aes(x=Lon, y=Lat, color=Species), ...)`, i.e. adding a mapping between `color` and `Species` within `aes()`. Without example data it's hard to test though.

Comment: Try: `geom_point(data=genAQ, aes(x=Lon, y=Lat, color = Species, shape = Quality), size=1)`

Comment: Thank you both, that worked perfectly! I was sure I had attempted what you both had suggested but obviously had gotten the final bracket incorrectly placed. My graph looks perfect now.